# link_to by association models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, link-to

- ruby 1.9.2p290
- rails 3.1.1

I have two models: RECIPE and RECIPE_CATEGORY with "belongs_to" and "has_many" association respectively.

I can list all recipes by category nicely by this url:

http://localhost:3001/recipes/salads

But in my "link_to" that points to recipe list by category seem working only in your own action: **recipes#list_by_category**.

```
<%= link_to recipe.recipe_category.name, recipe_category_recipes_path(@recipe_categories) %>
```

**RecipesController**

```
def index  
 @recipes = Recipe.where({ :status_id => 1 }).includes(:chef, :recipe_category).order("updated_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(
end 

def list_by_category
 @recipe_category = RecipeCategory.find_by_name_plural(params[:recipe_category_id])
 @recipes = @recipe_category.recipes.where(:status_id => 1).includes(:chef).order("id desc").page(params[:page]).per(9)
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :recipes, :id => /[0-9]+/ do
 match 'pagina/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection # Kaminari
 # list of recipes by category
 get 'recipe_category', :to => 'recipes#list_by_category', :path => ':recipe_category_id', :on => :collection, :recipe_category_id => /[a-z]+/
end
```

**Desired URLS**

- localhost:3001/recipes/ *- list of recipes*
- localhost:3001/recipes/21681 *- show recipe's page*
- localhost:3001/recipes/salads *- show recipes by category*
- localhost:3001/recipes/lunch *- show recipes by hour of day*

So, how to build a "link_to" that points to recipes by category across all actions?

Am I clear? Let me know if I not.

**Edit**

**RecipesController**

```
def index
  if params[:category_id]
    @category = Category.find_by_slug(params[:category_id])
    @recipes = @category.recipes.where(:status_id => 1).includes(:chef).order("updated_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(9)
  else
    @recipes = Recipe.where({ :status_id => 1 }).includes(:chef, :category).order("updated_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(9)
    @count_all = Recipe.where({ :status_id => 1 }).count()
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :categories, :path => "recipes/categories", :only => :index do
  resources :recipes, :path => "", :only => :index do
    match 'pagina/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
  end
end
resources :recipes, :path => 'receitas', :id => /[0-9]+/ do
   match 'pagina/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
end
```

**URLS**

- localhost:3001/recipes *- list all recipes*
- localhost:3001/recipes/categories *- list all categories*
- localhost:3001/recipes/categories/salads *- list recipes by category

**SOLUTION**

```
<%= link_to recipe.name, category_recipes_path(recipe.category.slug) %>
```

Comment: I have to say: Rails is about following naming conventions that tend to make things obvious and easy.  "RecipeCategory" is not the usual name for a model.  Category is a model.  Recipe is a model.  Once you think about it that way, I think the answer to your question may be a little more obvious.   Ok, so I have that off my chest :-)

The general answer: routes are used to establish URLs that map to controller actions.  If you follow the REST pattern you'll save yourself some work and confusion.

Comment: Hi tharrison, thanks for answer. I'm new on ruby/rails as you seeing.

But, about name's models, I must to say there are many types of categories in this project like TipCategory, MenuCategory, etc...This was the way I  Found to organizing all kinds of category.

Do you have a suggestion about the names in this case?

And about the "link_to"? I'm a little confused about link_to construction, and I believe thats isn't just about to naming convention.

Thanks.

Comment: Naming is at the heart of how Rails works -- it replaces a great deal of configuration you would otherwise need.  Perhaps if you have multiple types of categories, you could add a "type" field in the category table?  If you're just seeking the answer, I have added one below :-).

Comment: Sorry, didn't add an answer; with respect and understanding, it looks like you're "fighting against" Rails, and that will cause you no end of pain (I know, I have scars :-).  Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to understand this complicated but important part of how Rails works.

Comment: I've read several times all rails guide, include the routing. I just post this question because I realy don't know what else to do. Ok, the naming could be a "problem", but I want to know about the "link_to" trough this specific association. I will put a type field in category, thank for that. But this name change still don't help me with link_to question. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a link to a page that lists all the recipes in a given category, what may work best is to set up the recipes as a nested resource of the recipe_category: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

The routing would look something like:

```
resources :recipe_categories do
  resources :recipes
end
```

This would allow you to use a link like this:

```
recipe_category_recipes_path(recipe_category)
```

which would route to a page that would display all the recipes in the recipe_category.  If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify in your question.

**Edit:**

You could tack on a parameter to the index url, and add a catch in your index that would filter the standard index view down to only the recipes that matched the parameter.

So your rails link to calls would look like this:

```
recipes_path(:category => @category)
recipes_path(:time => @time)
```

Which would result in urls that look like this:

```
localhost:3001/recipes?category=salads
localhost:3001/recipes?time=lunch
```

And your index method in your recipes controller could be changed to something like this:

```
def index 
    if params[:category]
        Recipe.where("category = ?", params[:category])
    else if params[:time]
        Recipe.where("time = ?", params[:time])
    else 
        @recipes = Recipe.all
    end
end
```

This isn't the prettiest, and I'm not sure how "rails" this approach is, but it works for me in these situations.  Let me know if this is what you are looking for, or if I missed again.

Comment: Hi, I've changed the model's name as advised above (thanks tharrison).

numbersnelson, could you look at my desired urls? I need some custom urls and I couldn't simply use nested resource like your advice. Or am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check out my edited response with another way around this and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi numbersnelson! Thank you very much for spend your time! I realy liked your suggestion to put into one action only. I did some changes in routes too. Thanks. BUT, the recipes_path(:category => @category) only works when I have the params[:category]. I want to work in all conditions from index action. How to do that? Am I clear? Sorry about my english!

Comment: In your index method, the code under the "if params[:category]" statement will be run if the parameter is present, but if you simply use the "recipes_path" with no param value for category, the code under the "else" section will be run.  In the example above, if you navigate use the " recipes_path(:category => @category) " with a category value, the "Recipe.where("category = ?", params[:category])" will be run.  If you use "recipes_path", the "@recipes = Recipe.all" will be run, returning all recipes like a normal index method would.

Comment: I put my modifications to you look.

I didn't have sucess to create a "link_to" in "localhost:3001/recipes" that appoint to the list recipes by category. In recipe's list I have the category name of each recipe and I want to create a link that shows a list of recipes by category.

Doesn't works if I use recipes_path(:category_id => @category) in "localhost:3001/recipes". Sorry about my stupid questions, but I can't figure out yet. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Can you update your questions with the modifications you made and indicate what type of error you are getting after you make the changes? Posting your controller and view code would be helpful in determining what you are doing wrong.

Comment: It works now! I changed the url to "recipes/CATEGORIES/salads".
I'm using the following url: "category_recipes_path(recipe.category.slug)" and everything is just fine right now. Thank you very much!